# routing between angular js and symfony 2

Tags: angularjs, symfony

How to make routing of a symfony application in angular js ,I have a symfony application with its templates and I can make the routing of the templates of this application by angular js

thanks you

Comment: so, you want angularjs be a router? I don't get the point at all

Comment: yes i want angular js be a router

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you mean to ask, but probably you are looking for a way to access your Symfony routes in Angular.

In that case, take a look at the
[FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)

It provides a javascript object that you can use to generate urls much like the path() function in Twig. For example:

```
Routing.generate('your_route', {'foo': 'bar'})
```

You only need a [few steps](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/installation.html) in order use use.

Comment: The problem that I find is for example I have an action adding a product from a form , when it fact routing with angularjs , the action is not works is when he was appointed to the action with the routing of symfony , the action is works well
why I find this problem?